# Fitnesse cannot find class unless it has a wiki page

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

I'm running into some odd behavior when trying to setup an ActionFixture test using Fitnesse (with FitSharp as the test runner)

When creating an actionFixture I'll get an error that the class (Namespace.TestClassName in example below) cannot be found.  If I create a wiki page for it the test will work.

```
| actionFixture |
| start | Namespace.TestClassName |
```

Is it required to have a page for each class?  If so can I reference the same page for all tests (different location in hierarchy)?

Sorry for the naive question, sure I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error on my part;

Needed to enclose the class name as shown below

```
| actionFixture |
| start | !-Namespace.TestClassName-! |
```

...or simply don't write the name as a wikiword;

```
| actionFixture |
| start | namespace.testClassName |
```